# Login to a secure web page using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

my name is Francisco, I am currently trying to automate the generation of a daily report downloaded from a web page but I am struggling to pass the login page.

I don't need to input the login info since it is already there. I just need a line of code to press the login button on the page.

so far my goes like this:

```
 Set ObjIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ObjIE.Top = 0
    ObjIE.Left = 0
    ObjIE.Width = 800
    ObjIE.Height = 600
    ObjIE.AddressBar = 0
    ObjIE.StatusBar = 0
    ObjIE.Toolbar = 0

    ObjIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation

    ObjIE.Navigate ("http://kirby.inst.strykercorp.com")
```

Html code of the page when look for the source code of the button:

```
 <FORM id=loginForm method=post name=form action=j_security_check><TABLE <TR>

    <INPUT onclick=checkSave() type=submit value=Login></TD>
```

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDc6e.jpg)

Please help.

Thanks!

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JciEi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1)

```
ObjIE.document.querySelector("[value=Login]").click
```

2)

```
ObjeIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "checkSave();"
```

3)

```
Dim event_onClick As Object
Set event_onClick = ObjIE.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
event_onClick.initEvent "click", True, False

ObjIE.document.querySelector("[value=Login]").dispatchEvent event_onClick
```

4)

```
ObjIE.document.querySelector("[value=Login]").FireEvent "onclick"
```

5)

```
ObjIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('[value=Login]').click();"
```

Comment: Hi QHarr thank you for answering that quick! I added the line but I am getting the Run Time error' "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebrowser2' failed" what do you think could be error? thanks        I

Comment: any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Does it happen each time?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that this site is part  of the company intranet. Could this be cause of error?

Comment: Yes. Ensure site is on whitelist and also try using internetexplorermedium instead of internetexplorer.

Comment: by whitelist, what do you mean? how can I ensure is on the whitelist? i will give a try and let you know in a few hours. thanks

Comment: Is the site on a list of sites you are allowed to visit? Your browser will normally allow you to add sites considered safe

Comment: Sorry I was out of the office until today, Ok, I have tried this line: Set ObjIE = CreateObject("Internetexplorermedium.Application") , but I am now receiving another error: Run time eror '429'": ActiveX component cant create object

Comment: Try Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: ok I have changed to code to"                                       

Dim ObjIE As Object    
Set ObjIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    ObjIE.Top = 0
    ObjIE.Left = 0
    ObjIE.Width = 800
    ObjIE.Height = 600
    ObjIE.AddressBar = 0
    ObjIE.StatusBar = 0
    ObjIE.Toolbar = 0

    ObjIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation

    ObjIE.Navigate ("http://kirby.inst.strykercorp.com")
    

    ObjIE.Document.querySelector("[value=Login]").Click

Comment: the debug is highlighting line: ObjIE.Document.querySelector("[value=Login]").Click

Comment: And what message are you getting?

Comment: Run time error ' -2147467259(80004005): Method 'Document' of Object 'IWebBrowser2'Failed

Comment: Weird. You can pastebin.com the entire page html but don't make it as an edit to the answer above.

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: I will have a machine to run vba on again tomorrow.

Comment: great, did you have the chance to review the full code on pastebin?

Comment: Please see list of options

Comment: let me know how goes

Comment: Great! I was out of the office on a business trip and wasn’t able to try it. I will test the options tomorrow. Thank you again!